# Jacobian for transformation of rotation angles

Tags: robotic-arm, mechanism, jacobian

It is known that with the help of the Jacobi matrix it is possible to transform the angular velocities of the drive links $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ into the angular velocity of the platform $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ through the Jacobi matrix.

$\boldsymbol{\Omega}=\boldsymbol{J}\boldsymbol{\omega}$

where $\boldsymbol{J}$ - Jacobi matrix.

*What matrix is used to transform the corresponding angular positions?*

$\boldsymbol{\Theta}=?\boldsymbol{\theta}$

Answer (score 1):

You use Forward Kinematics to calculate the end-effector pose of your robot/platform, given the joint angles.

There are many different methods to calculate the Forward Kinematics, I remember using the Product of Exponentials method, which works well if you have a good visual model/description of your platform. You may use Geometric Methods and functions (trigonometric) if you have a fairly simple platform, such as a SCARA Robot. Also, I have never used it but I believe that the most common approach to Forward Kinematics is something called "Denavit–Hartenberg Parameters". You can make a search on these ones according to your platform and needs.

If you want to know about this because of a position-following application; for example if you want your platform to follow a position trajectory, and desire to calculate the joint angles; you use an iterative approach to achieve that. If that is the case you can have a look one of my previous answers, regarding a similar case by clicking [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/22191/26789):

Comment: This transformation is difficult to represent in the form of any matrix.

Comment: Why such a matrix does not exist for rotation angles? If $\dot{\theta}=J\dot{\omega}$, then $\theta=\int J\dot{\omega}  dt$? Is it possible to find out what kind of formula (I mean, without integrals) lies behind $\int J\dot{\omega}  dt$.

Comment: You wish to take the integral of the dot product of two matrices, right? Whether it is Jacobian, Inverse Jacobian, linear or angular velocities; they are matrices. When you wish to integrate a product of matrices, you do that by a some kind of "Product of Exponentials" formula. I actually never tried to integrate this expression, however, I strongly believe that it will point out to the relation between the Forward Kinematics via. Product of Exponentials and the Jacobian. I believe that this answer may show some guidance for you: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/537571/789117

Comment: Well. I'll try to extract something useful. Thank you very much :)